# Parcel Number from Google Places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know if Google Places or perhaps another API is able to look up a property APN (assessor's parcel number) by address?

I'm using Google Places to get the address and update fields in a form, and I'd also like to populate the APN field based on the property address.

Comment: Places API doesn't expose APN. There is a feature request in issue tracker to make APN available: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63286055.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**, the API is not *publicly available*, but you can request an invitation here:
https://rets.ly/docs/platform.html

My first thought was the [Zillow API](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/PropertyDetailsAPIOverview.htm) but I don't think they provide APNs.

[The Bridge, formarly Rets.ly API](https://rets.ly/docs/platform.html), allows you to query by lat/lng and get back a parcel number. AFAIK they won't geocode for you, but if you are already using a google api, you should be able to get them to geocode, and then pass the lat/lng onto Bridge.

An example GET request might look like

```
https://rets.io/api/v2/pub/parcels?access_token=$token&near=41.9171124,-87.6475581&limit=1
```

with a response like

```
{
  "success": true,
  "status": 200,
  "bundle": [
    {
      "id": "372176",
      "fips": "17031",
      "apn": "14333001270000",
      "county": "Cook",
      "state": "IL",
   //...
```